# How do pass a String value to a JS function within this PHP --> HTML --> JS Code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I am trying to call a JS function within an HTML input tag. **This tag is itself within PHP code** and the function works absolutely fine with just int values, so I know the problem is something to do with how i'm passing the string. see below.

```
foreach($res as $row) {
        $rowNumber = $row["RowNumber"];
        $price = $row["Price"];
            echo "<tr><td>".$row["RowNumber"]."</td>"." "."<td>". 
            $row["Price"]."</td><td><form method='POST' 
            action='book.php'>
            <input type='checkbox' name='$i' 
            onclick='totalSummary($price,'$rowNumber');'>
            </form></td></tr>";
            $i++;
        }
```

this loop is pulling each `$row` from a SQL database and then posting a checkbox. Upon clicking this checkbox, I want to call the JS function `totalSummary()` which passes through an int value (the cost of the specified seat) and the row number of type String. the problem is that when I call the function with just `$price` the function is called successfully. but when I try to pass through a STRING as well it doesn't pick it up. See below JS code (which is also within and is written AFTER the above code):

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            var totalPrice = 0;
            var seatsSelected = [];
            function totalSummary(cost,seats){
                alert(totalPrice);
                totalPrice = totalPrice + cost;
                seatsSelected.push(seats);
            }
            function displayTotal(){

                alert('Seats selected: ' + seats.join(',') + \ntotalPrice);
            }
            </script>";
```

The alert call is only there so I can see the function is called. But it doesn't appear when I check a box.

Help would be appreciated as i'm pulling my hair out!

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to happen, what is happening and are you getting any errors? If it works with int values but you want to do calculations with strings, then you first need to parse them to a number, otherwise '1' + '1' will equal '11'

Comment: Step 1: Check what the actual HTML code this foreach loop outputs looks like. (And after that, step 2 is likely either reading http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php or http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)

Comment: So I basically have a list of row numbers (e.g. U01) of type String and the cost of those to book (e.g 15.00). I would like the totalSummary function to add the cost of the seat to the total value. So if 3 checkboxes are ticked and all of these checkboxes are linked to seats that have a value of £15 then totalPrice will be 45. I then want the row numbers to be added to an array of strings so I can display all the selected seats at the end. I am getting no error it's just the function isn't being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an issue with quotes inside the first code block.
You use single quote to wrap both the onclick function and the $rowNumber value `onclick='totalSummary($price,'$rowNumber');'`
Try something like
`onclick=\"totalSummary($price,'$rowNumber');\"`

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you so much